# Why does my bisectional approach fail for certain secret words in hangman?

Tags: python, bisection

I've recently started learning Python through an intro online class. The instructor just introduced bisection algorithms, and I'm trying to apply it to a game of hangman. However, my code gets caught in a never ending loop for certain 'secret words', but not for others. For example, it can guess the word "wife", but not "wifey". However, it can guess the word "y". I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure it out. (As an aside, I do realize this code won't work for the letter 'z', but that is a separate problem.)

```
secret_word = 'wifey'
num_guesses = 0
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
guessed_word = ''
low = 0
high = len(alphabet)+2

while len(guessed_word) != len(secret_word):
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        guess_index = 0
        while alphabet[guess_index] != secret_word[i]:
            if ord(alphabet[guess_index]) < ord(secret_word[i]):
                low = guess_index
            else: high = guess_index
            num_guesses += 1
            guess_index = int((high + low)/2)
        else: guessed_word += alphabet[guess_index]
print('num_guesses =', num_guesses)
print(guessed_word)
```

Comment: Thanks, @AsiriHewage! Any suggestions on how to better update the low and high in the loop? The bisectional approach uses this approach for numerical applications, but it isn't working quite as well for this use case. Also, I removed the epsilon since I'm not using in this version of the code.

Comment: You initialise `low` and `high` only once at the start of the code, but this should be done for each position in the target word (i.e. at the start of the `for i` loop)

Comment: A nice question to think about is what property the word "wife" has which means the program can still guess it despite the bug :)

Comment: A suggestion on how to better update the high and low values -- make a function for your binary search.

Comment: A side note -- you don't need `ord` there.  You can compare one-character strings directly.